# How to make list scrolling only with mouse (actionscript 3)

Tags: actionscript-3, list, mouseevent, mouse

You can see this list here http://www.studia-kuhni.ru/exec.swf.

```
List.change
List.itemRollOut
List.itemRollOver
List.scroll
```

What I should use? How I can scroll list as like as on that swf? (i know about tweenmax, question about scrolling)

May be somebody know beautiful and well made examples?
Thank you.

Comment: Could you elaborate on what you want to do? To my knowledge, the user can scroll through a list using the mousewheel by default. Do you want to know how to make images appear when an item is selected?

Comment: yes, now i use event.target.selectedItem.data (on mouse click) and i want it by scroll.

Comment: Have you tried any of the events you mentioned? If I understand correctly, I would expect "scroll" to work.

Comment: With Event:SCROLL selected item doesn't change, how i can change selected item by scrolling?

Answer (score 0):

Try using List.scroll listener, and update 'selectedIndex' with respect to the scroll direction. For eg., my_list.selectedIndex += 1 to select the next item.

Comment: it's working, but then im scrolling it selected item going down faster than scrolling pane and i didn't see selected item label

Comment: this might help - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5120420/flex-list-scroll-speed-with-mouse-wheel

Comment: hm added verticalLineScrollSize = 5; and now it's ok, but I'm still thinking there are some better solutions as like as on link below. thanks

Comment: how to make selected item unable to scroll at last down position (while scrolling)?